# Изменение внешнего вида GUI-элементов Java

Tags: gui, java, swing

Возможно ли изменять графический вид окна и других элементов управления, или создавать их самому? Если есть какие-то материалы на эту тему, сбросьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: Можно поточнее, что вы имеете в виду под изменением внешнего вида? Имеете ли вы в виду просто разукрасить стандартные элементы по-другому или же речь о каких-то функциональных изменениях?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В простом случае придется использовать наследования от компонента и переопределять метод paintComponent. Вот кстати хорошая статья на хабре: [Улучшаем интерфейс Java-приложения](http://habrahabr.ru/company/alee/blog/117430/)

Answer (score 2):

Копайте про `Java Swing LookAndFeel`.